# java.util.Scanner recognizing German special characters

Tags: java

I am trying to get input from console in eclipse. But when i write special German character like 'ß', the character doesn't recognize and it comes like '??'.

My code is below. I tried `Locale.GERMANY` but it didn't works.

```
Scanner s = null;
Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");

try {
    s = new Scanner(System.in);
    s.useLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

    System.out.println(s.locale());

    while (s.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(s.next());
    }
} finally {
    if (s != null) {
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your operating system's encoding configuration? On a German Windows, the default is cp1252.

Comment: This code works just fine for me.

Comment: i use windows 7 english, language settings is english - us.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = new Scanner(System.in, "Windows-1252");
```

The constructor of Scanner has a constructor with encoding. The constructor without encoding
uses the default platform encoding.
That `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");` evidently misled the Scanner to use UTF-8.

Clarification: System.in uses the OS encoding, hence Windows-1252 for the German locale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't works, the output is 'ÃƒÅ¸'

Comment: @karlkeller: because you're telling Java to treat the console as if it handled UTF-8. Which it doesn't. **Why** did you add that `setProperty()` call there? Setting `file.encoding` is a *bad idea*.

Comment: @JoachimSauer is right; you could remove the locale stuff and setting the file.encoding.

Comment: The console window of an IDE adds to possible pitfalls. So did you run from Windows cmd.exe?